# postgresql remove last 4 characters from text values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with only one column that has multiple text values. All of them end with same 4 characters that I would like to remove.
Could anyone, please, help me with a query for that?

I've already tried 'replace'

```
SELECT REPLACE(ticker, 'USDT', '') FROM tickers;
```

It appears to do what I want, but it doesn't update my data in a table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is the issue with your query?  And why are you storing multiple values in a string?  That is probably the root cause of your problems -- it is the wrong way to store data in a relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `update` statement

```
UPDATE tickers
SET ticker = REPLACE(ticker, 'USDT', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about the last 4 character, you can update using below as well -

UPDATE tickers
SET ticker = SUBSTR(ticker,-4);